# Group set of similar values in a column

Tags: r

[Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdhtk.gif)

Hello, 
I am very new to R and was hoping someone can help me to get started on this project! I have attached a picture of my data frame above for clarity

so, my data frame has 20 columns and 20000 rows. 
I would like to group my data frame into a new or the old data frame by column "Name" where similar numbers to be grouped together and where The "model" column has more than one "D", i want the entire group to be deleted from the data frame. there are other columns in the data frame that i will need to use later but first step, i need to delete the grouping that has more than one D 
thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
data<-cbind.data.frame(
      name=sapply(1:200,FUN=function(x) x=paste0(sample(x=c("D","E","F","H","N"),size=5,replace = T),collapse = "")),
      value=rnorm(200))
```

Now, find out which rows in name column have more than two d (upper or lower case) `"[dD]{2,}"`

```
index<-grepl("[dD]{2,}",data$name)
```

And, at last subset your data:

```
data[!index,]
     name        value
1   DNNFD  0.710399226
2   FDFFN -1.140585633
3   FHDEF  0.319493935
4   HNEFE -1.161941990
5   HFEFE  0.087838201
6   EHDEF  0.983140773
```